# Converting existing python classes into Django Models

Tags: python, django

I have a small program with a command line interface that uses a number of python classes with thorough implementations.  I want to scrap the command line interface and wrap the app within a Django app, but I'm just learning Django and I'm unfamiliar with the conventions.

I have a number of classes, in-memory storage structures, getters/setters etc and I'd like to convert them into Django models so that I can persist them to the database and interact with them around the django app.  Is there a general approach for doing something like this?

Should I just inherit the django.db.models.Model class in my existing classes and set them up for direct interaction? Or is there a better, more general/conventional way to do this?

I would like to be able to use all of this code in other apps, not necesarilly Django ones, so I don't really want to modify my existing classes in a way that would make them only work with Django. I thought of creating the models separately and then a sort of middle-man class to manage interaction of the actual in-memory class with the django model class, but that just seems like more places I have to make changes when I extend/modify the code.

Thanks for any help ahead of time...

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would modify your existing classes to extend `models.Model` and maintain separate versions of these classes for use outside of Django.

This will keep your classes lean and maintainable within their respective environments.

You could also create a new class that extends both `models.Model` and your python model through multiple inheritance. However this will result in duplicate fields for the same data.

If you would like, post an example Model as a new question and tag me in a link to it here, and I can help you convert it.

Answer (score 1):

One of greatest django strengths is its ORM, if you want import i recommend you use it, and yes you would probably need rewrite the part that interacts with the database, but if you already have isolated this functions in a Models folder~classes, the modification won't be really hard

Although in your case i would recommending checking out Tornado/Aiohttp Since looks like you are just trying to create a interface for your functions